# Databricks delete managed tables from Unity Catalog and File system

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

According [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-drop-table.html) deleting managed table will delete also all files and folders from the file system.
If I want to delete managed table using `%sql drop catalog.schema.tablename`, table is deleted from the Unity Catalog. But I can till see delta files and folders in ADLS storage.
I think those files and folders should be deleted together with the table from Unity Catalog.
Any advice what is wrong here?

Delta table I want to delete:
[image]

Files I can still see in the ADLS gen2 where is metastore located:
[image]

Comment: "When a managed table is dropped from Unity Catalog, its underlying data is deleted from your cloud tenant within 30 days." - According to the documentation you provided :)

Comment: Is there anything more about it? Because this is weird and provokes many further questions. Why not immediately? How exactly data will be deleted - some background task on UC side? What if storage is disconnected from UC before that happens? Why unclear "within" (which actually can mean anytime between 0 and 30 days)? What happens if I create a table with the same name?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. 
I tried setting the below properties as well, but the underlying files in cloud storage is not getting deleted.
SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration' = '5 minutes', 'delta.logRetentionDuration' = '2 minute');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will delete the "actual" data files in 30 day (which is the default Delta Log retention day).

Or, you can also manually delete the data files by running **VACCUM** against it.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/history.html#configure-data-retention-for-time-travel-queries

Answer (score 0):

"*When a managed table is dropped, its underlying data is deleted from your cloud tenant within 30 days*."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/